# Help! I don't understand this sentence's meaning

Tags: meaning

I'm reading Harry Potter for English study.

"Gryffindors have never gone so long without winning"

I think double negative means postive. So I think "Gryffindors have never gone so long without winning" means "Gryffindors have gone so long with winning".

But I heard that it means Gryffindors have been losing for a long time: their longest time ever.

Can you explain why???

Answer (score 2):

OP's example isn't what we normally mean by "double negation" in English (that's colloquial / uneducated usages such as *He **didn't** do **nothing** wrong*, where the two negatives *don't* "cancel each other out").

The cited example is just a straightforward literal usage. Gryffindors haven't won for a long time. So long, in fact, that they're currently experiencing their ***longest ever*** [losing streak](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/losing-streak) (extended period of losing / not winning).

Comment: *There has never been a losing streak as long as this one*

Comment: *Gryffindors have never **had such a long losing streak** [before]*.